# How to use SELECT COUNT sql to generate an int

Tags: python, mysql

I have this code in python querying an existing database:

```
count = db.execute("SELECT COUNT (player_id) FROM players WHERE user_id 
= :id", id = session["user_id"])

for player in range(count):
    db.execute("INSERT INTO live_players (player_id) VALUES (:filler)", 
filler = 0)
```

However, it doesn't run because 'count' isn't an int. I want SELECT COUNT to return 2, but instead it returns '[{'COUNT (player_id)': 2}]'. How could I remedy this?

Answer (score 1):

You're getting back a result dictionary. Simply access it. To make this access easier, give it an alias:

```
SELECT COUNT(player_id) AS player_count ...
```

Then:

```
for player in range(count["player_count"]):
   ...
```

Comment: I did this but got this error: list indices must be integers or slices, not str.

Comment: 'count' now returns '[{'player_count': 2}]' instead of '[{'COUNT (player_id)': 2}]'. Also, I used alecxe's suggestion, but it still didn't work.

Comment: That should be a simple dict, so you should be able to fetch the value you want. Alexce was right, that was a typo. It could also be `count[0]["player_count"]` if that's a nested structure.